# html5 video still can not play in android

Tags: html, video

hi i'm launching a site here:
http://dxc-server.com/drbrownsbeta/

however the video(.mp4) is not playable in Android. The codec already h.264
the mp4 width : 1056, height:400 can this become a problem ? i'm using mediaelementjs.com's player

i tried using handbrake converter and also failed...

the file can be download here :http://dxc-server.com/drbrownsbeta/images/videos/babybottle.mp4

any idea what to do..

i tried to copy the several mp4 with different handbrake profile in my android.. but there's nothing work

could the movie resolution become the problem?

UPDATE: I tried videojs's player (http://www.dxc-server.com/drbrownsbeta/videojs.html) and the problem still exist, i'm sure this is a the video problem not a script problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your video is encoded with [H.264 High Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles).  Some of the latest Android devices support High Profile, but if you want it to work on all Android devices then stick to Baseline Profile (see [Android core media format and codec support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)).

Also, your video has the `moov` atom at the end.  If you want the video to be playable before the whole thing has downloaded, you will need to move the `moov` (metadata) before the `mdat` (video data).  You can do that using the [`qt-faststart`](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide#OptionalInstallation) program that comes with [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/), or [this python version](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart), or one of the others referenced on [this page](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/), or [`mp4box`](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/), or a similar program.